# What Happens When I Create Getters and Setters in Python Code?

Tags: python, getter-setter

So, I am on my journey of learning Python, currently going through the OOP concepts. Here's a sample program:

```py
class Time:
    def __init__(self, hour=0, minute=0, second=0):
        self.hour = hour
        self.minute = minute
        self.second = second

    @property
    def hour(self):
        """Return the hour"""
        return self._hour

    @hour.setter
    def hour(self, hour):
        """Set the hour"""
        if not (0 <= hour < 24):
            raise ValueError("Hour must be between 0 and 23")

        self._hour = hour

    @property
    def minute(self):
        """Return the hour"""
        return self._minute

    @minute.setter
    def minute(self, minute):
        """Set the minute"""
        if not(0 <= minute < 60):
            raise ValueError("Minute must be between 0 and 59")

        self._minute = minute

    @property
    def second(self):
        """Return the seconds"""
        return self._second

    @second.setter
    def second(self, second):
        """Set the second"""
        if not (0 <= second < 60):
            raise ValueError("Second must be between 0 and 59")

        self._second = second


wake_up = Time(6, 45)
```

So, am I right in assuming that when any `Time` object (in this case, `wake_up`) is created, the getter and setter methods will be automatically called? In other words:

1. In the `__init__` method, for example, when I say `self.hour = hour`, the `hour` method will be automatically called and the arguments from init method will be passed into it?
2. Anywhere else in the class definition, if I call `self.hour`, the `hour` method will be called as well?
3. In the `hour` getter/setter methods, do I have to necessarily use the `_` with the variable name, or is that just a convention to follow?

Thanks!

Comment: What have your independent tests shown?

Comment: Your properties aren't implemented correctly. Your `__init__` should be defining `self._hour`, `self._minute`, `self._second`, and your properties will then work how they're supposed to.

Comment: @ddejohn They'll work just fine if you want your setter logic to encompass object instantiation as well.

Comment: It's not great practice to set new attributes in places other than in `__init__`...

Comment: In fact, there's no reason to duplicate any logic for assigning to the property in both `__init__` and in the property's setter.

Comment: Properties are an *application* of the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html); knowing how properties use the protocol isn't necessary to use properties, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes. Getters and setters are used anywhere the attribute is referenced, whether inside or ouside the class.
2. Yes, for the same reason.
3. The `_` prefix is just a naming convention, you can call the attribute anything you want, as long as it's different from the property.